# Help with a simple C programming exercise

Tags: c

I'm new to C programming, having a bit of difficulty with a programming exercise, I'm sure this is simple for anyone who knows C, unfortunately you have to play by the rules of the exercise.

Here's the exercise:

> Have a program request the user to
>   enter an uppercase letter. Use nested
>   loops to produce a pyramid pattern
>   like this:
>
> ```
>     A 
>
>    ABA
>
>   ABCBA
>
>  ABCDCBA
>
> ABCDEDCBA
> ```
>
> The pattern should extend to the
>   character entered. For example, the
>   preceding pattern would result from an
>   input value of E. Hint: Use an outer
>   loop to handle the rows. Use three
>   inner loops in a row, one to handle
>   the spaces, one for printing letters
>   in ascending order, and one for
>   printing letters in descending order.

**So I got this far:**

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {

 int rows;
 int spaces;

 char asc;
 char desc;
 char input;

 printf("Please enter an uppercase letter: ");
 scanf("%c", &input);

 for (rows = 'A'; rows <= input; rows++) {
  for (spaces = input; spaces > rows; spaces--) {
   printf(" ");
  }
  for (asc = 'A'; asc <= rows; asc++) {
   printf("%c", asc);
  }
  for (desc = asc - 2; desc >= rows; desc--) {
   printf("%c", desc);
  }
  printf("\n");
 }
 return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're very close:

```
for (desc = asc - 2; desc >= 'A'; desc--) {
```

Note that after the second inner loop, `asc` is `rows + 1`.  You're then initializing `desc` to `rows - 1`.  You should be able to see why `>= rows` is wrong, and will result in no iterations.

The correct condition is simply `>= 'A'`.

Comment: Wow, that's painful. Thanks dude. Had been looking at that damn line for about an hour.

Comment: @Corey: If this answered your question, click the tick outline to turn it green and give Matthew the kudos.

Comment: Yeah, I tried to do that earlier but I got some random "you have to wait 10 minutes before marking this as answered" message. Tis done now!